# SQL Convert String hh:mm:ss to Decimal Hour

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala, hue

I have a column lvl_tim in a table which is a string type returned as hh:mm:ss. I cannot take a datefiff() approach and ultimately would like to sum the values.

I have attempted:

```
cast(lvl_tim as int)
```

My desired result is 0:10:10 to be returned as 0.1683hrs.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You could just take the brute force arithmetic approach:

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '12:34:56' AS time
)

SELECT
    time,
    CAST(LEFT(time, 2) AS int) +
    CAST(SUBSTRING(time, 4, 2) AS int) / 60.0 +
    CAST(SUBSTRING(time, 7, 2) AS int) / (60.0*60.0) AS decimal_hours
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The correct output from the above query is `12.58222155` decimal hours, given an input time of `12:34:56`.

Comment: Thank you Tim, subsequently this is the same operation I did in Excel - ha! I did post in my question I had attempted cast(), however after playing more and attempting your solution, I've determined it is not supported.